# Insert odd position elements from another array elements

Tags: javascript

I have an array which looks like this [1,0,3,0,5,0] what I want is that I want to insert the zero elements the elements of this array [2,4,6] so the complete array should look like this [1,2,3,4,5,6].

```
let a = [1,0,3,0,5,0]

let b = [2,4,6]
// expected output [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: Okay, so, what's your attempt?

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: Please add your attempt to the question...

Comment: do you want a new array or mutated `a`?

Comment: I want new array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `forEach` in this case for a mutating solution:

```js
let a = [1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0];
let b = [2, 4, 6, 8]
a.forEach((i, j) => {
  if (i === 0)
    a[j] = b[~~(j / 2)] // integer division
})
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a variable for the index for finding falsy values and insert the replacement value at this index.

```js
let data = [1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0],
    replacements = [2, 4, 6],
    i = 0;
    
for (const value of replacements) {
    while (data[i]) i++;
    data[i] = value;
}

console.log(data);
```

For getting a new array, you could map the data array with the replacements.

```js
let data = [1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0],
    replacements = [2, 4, 6],
    result = data.map(v => v || replacements.shift());

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below approach with work:

```js
x = [1,0,3,0,5,0]
y = [2,4,6]

j = 0;
for(i = 0; i < x.length; i ++) {
    if(x[i] === 0 && j < y.length)
        x[i] = y[j++];
}

console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
const a = [1,0,3,0,5,0];
const b = [2,4,6];

let lastIndex = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
  lastIndex = a.indexOf(0, lastIndex);
  a[lastIndex] = b[i];
}

console.log(a);
```